# Unable to navigate from a bottomTab Navigator to a Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate from a `bottomTabNavigator Screen` which is `Home` to a `Stack Navigator Screen` which is `Trip` using React Navigation.

In my NavigationContainer I have a function which contains the `AppNavigator`(this uses `createBottomNavigator`) and the `AuthenticationNavigator`(this uses the `createStackNavigator`).

In my `App.js` it checks if the user is logged in or not and then from there shows the right navigation for the user. If the user is logged in then they can access `AppNavigator` and the `HomeScreenNavigator`.

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'initializing' && <Initializing />}
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'loggedIn' &&
        (<AppNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} /> 
        ))}
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'loggedOut' && (
        <AuthenticationNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

What I did was to add in `HomeScreenNavigator` which will contain all the screens that the user can access under the `BottomTabNavigator` screen, `Home` and all the nested screens inside of `Home` use `Stack Navigators`.

```
  const HomeScreenNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Trip" component={Trip} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

`AppNavigator` which is used for `bottomTabNavigation` when the user is logged in. Here is the `Home` component from which I am navigating over to the `Trip` component.

#### **I do not know how to pass in the `HomeScreenNavigator` into this `bottomTabNavigation` or if it is even possible. When the user is logged in this is the only Navigaton that should be able to used by the user.**

```
  const AppNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <BottomTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            let iconName = '';

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = 'home';
            } else if (route.name === 'User Profile') {
              iconName = 'person';
            }
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'black',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}>
        <BottomTab.Screen name="Home">
            <Home updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState} />
        </BottomTab.Screen>
        <BottomTab.Screen name="User Profile">
            <UserProfile
              updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState}
            />
        </BottomTab.Screen>
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

`AuthenticationNavigator` which handles the stack navigation for all the authentication processes.

```
  const AuthenticationNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn">
            <SignIn updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState} />
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ConfirmSignUp" component={ConfirmSignUp} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

This is the `Home` component from where when the user clicks a button they will be navigated over to the `Trip` component which currently just shows the text `Trip`.

```
export default function Home({updateAuthState, navigation}) {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AppButton
        title="Start a trip"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Trip');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Right now when the user clicks on the button the error they get is the following even though I already set the screen name `Trip` under `HomeScreenNavigator`.

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Trip"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

Comment: could you reproduce it in a snack ? https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/navigators. I think you didn't add HomeScreenNavigator to BottomNavigator. This syntax is wrong {isUserLoggedIn === 'loggedIn' &&
        (<AppNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} /> || (
          <HomeScreenNavigator />
        ))} that or don't make sense you should put HomeScreenNavigator inner AppNavigator

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz but if I put it under the `AppNavigator` wouldn't it become a bottom tab screen? I want it to be a nested screen and not part of the bottom tab navigation. I am away from my computer I will add it in a snack later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue and here is what I did.

In the `AppNavigator` I moved all the screens and their components that would be under the `Home Screen` to `HomeScreenNavigator`.

```
  const HomeScreenNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Trip" component={Trip} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

In the `AppNavigator` the Tab for all the screens under the Home Screen are passed in as a component.

```
const AppNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <BottomTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            let iconName = '';

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = 'home';
            } else if (route.name === 'User Profile') {
              iconName = 'person';
            }
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'black',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}>
        <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreenNavigator} updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState}/>
        <BottomTab.Screen name="User Profile">
            <UserProfile
              updateAuthState={props.updateAuthState}
            />
        </BottomTab.Screen>
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

Now when I am at the `Home Screen` and press the button to navigate to the `Trip` component it works as expected and there is a back button to navigate back to the `Home Screen`.